# Real Time Factor going down after insertion of a "simple" test room

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

after inserting a selfmade model, a floor (around 27 meters x 2,20 meters) with one additional room (around 4 meters x 5 meters), the real time factor is going down to 0.65. The model was created using sketup and exported as a .dae file (see attachement).

Of course I did expect the real time factor to go down a bit, but how much is considered normal with "simple" shapes.

The robot movements are becoming really slow. I am using the ROS move_base node to move to 2d goals.

The computer I use is an i7 @ 3,4GHz with 8GB ram. The graphics card is some nvidia with 1024MB. Could it be that the graphics card doesn't have enough power? Isn't the gazebo client normally not used for visual presentation and user interaction only?

Thanks for your help,
Christoph

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5027/real-time-factor-going-down-after-insertion-of-a-%22simple%22-test-room/) by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You are probably using the collada model for both the  and  in your SDF model file. A triangle mesh for  is very slow. I recommend using a set of simple shapes ( geometry, for example) for the  elements.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on 2013-11-18**:
Hey Nate! You are right. Do you know if I have to do this manually, like when I am building my own robot model, where I used simle shapes for the collisions zones? Because I dont reall know how to set such simple shapes in this case, where the model is designed as one part and not devided into multiple links. Besides I am inserting the model manually (at the time), so it isn't always in the same place. Cheers Christoph

**Comment by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on 2013-11-22**:
Hi! I took a simpler model of my floor and the real time factor went up a bit. Maybe I will try to make it even more simpler. Thanks for your help!